# Why can't I open downloads from Google Chrome's download bar?

Tags: finder, google-chrome

For some reason, clicking on downloads in the Google Chrome download bar does nothing any more; I'm pretty sure it did until some time recently, but it's been a while since it did.

Also, choosing "Show in Finder" doesn't work. So, it seems that Chrome in general can't open anything in the Finder.

If anyone knows what is causing that, I'd love to know it, or alternately, how I could go about troubleshooting it myself.

**Edit** in response to comments:

1. I've tried re-downloading it, although not running it from another directory; I'll try that at home.
2. I'll give it a shot.
3. No, the downloads list is no more functional than the download bar with respect to Finder integration.

Comment: Two things worth trying: 1) download Chrome again, and instead of dragging into Applications, drag to Desktop, run and see if it works; 2) creating a new user from Chrome (i.e. maybe some setting got screwed up on your account): Preferences -> Add new user

Comment: Also, does the "Open downloads folder" link work from within Downloads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's caused by a [bug in 10.8.2](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2012/10/04/aesendmessage-bug-in-mac-os-x-10-8-2/). Occasionally revealing files in Finder stops working in all applications, and for example Archive Utility stops responding when extracting archives.

As a workaround, you can terminate appleventsd from Activity Monitor or with `sudo killall -kill appleeventsd` (without -kill the process is sent a TERM signal, which makes other processes stop responding). The issue will probably return within a few hours or days though.

Comment: Oh my god. I love you so much right now, whoever you are. THANK YOU.

Comment: yes! this works on macbook air running 10.8.2